# Retry spring integration IntegrationFlow on exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-amqp, spring-integration-amqp

I have a spring integration `IntegrationFlow` that's defined like this:

```
IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(connectionFactory, "queueName")
                    .id("id")
                    .autoStartup(autoStartup)
                    .concurrentConsumers(2)
                    .maxConcurrentConsumers(3)
                    .messageConverter(messageConverter()))
                    .aggregate(a -> ...)
                    .handle(serviceActivatorBean)
                    .get();
```

And `serviceActivatorBean` looks like this:

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class ServiceActivator {

    @ServiceActivator

    public void myMethod(Collection<MyEvent> events) {
        ....
    }    
}
```

If `myMethod` throws an exception it will be logged but no retry will happen. I've tried to change the `IntegrationFlow` to this:

```
RequestHandlerRetryAdvice advice = new RequestHandlerRetryAdvice();
RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(5);
retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
advice.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate);

IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(connectionFactory, "queueName")
                    .id("id")
                    .autoStartup(autoStartup)
                    .adviceChain(advice)
                    .concurrentConsumers(2)
                    .maxConcurrentConsumers(3)
                    .messageConverter(messageConverter()))
                    .aggregate(a -> ...)
                    .handle(serviceActivatorBean)
                    .get();
```

But then I a log message like this (an retries won't happen):

> 2017-06-30 13:18:10.611  WARN 88706 --- [erContainer#1-2]
>   o.s.i.h.a.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice      : This advice
>   org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice
>   can only be used for MessageHandlers; an attempt to advise method
>   'invokeListener' in
>   'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1'
>   is ignored

How can I configure this `IntegrationFlow` to behave the same way a `RabbitListener` would? I.e. let RabbitMQ publish the messages again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [retry interceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#retry) in the adapter's advice chain instead of the `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice` - that is for consuming endpoints, as the message says.